# Cannot import Module without curly braces in react even after 'export default'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I have read somewhere that importing module in react with curly braces around imports the entire library instead and effectively increases the bundle size. I was using this concept and was successfull in importing modules without curly braces, like this: 
`import Jumbotron from 'reactstrap';`
and it was working fine. I don't know why the next time I build the code, it started showing me this warning:

`WARNING in ./React Coursera/Header.js 5:71-77
export default (imported as Jumbotron) was not found in reactstrap`.

Also the app didn't run in browser.

Then I went to node_modules to check if export default is present in jumbotron or not, and I found this statement:
`export default Jumbotron;`

It means that indeed it was exporting the Jumbotron as default, then why it showed me this warning.

Can you help me guys to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you read that importing with curly will increase the bundle size, it's reverse,

```
// below line will import everything
import * as reactstrap  from 'reactstrap'
```

But

```
// this will import only specific module
import { Jumbotron }  from 'reactstrap'
```

---

By this line :

```
// will import from /reactstrap/index.js
import Jumbotron from 'reactstrap';
```

You are importing nothing https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/index.js , as there is export default

So I don't know how it worked before in your case

Below line :

```
// and this line is not inside the /reactstrap/index.js but /reactstrap/Jumbotron.js
export default Jumbotron;
```

is here : https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/master/src/Jumbotron.js

So you can do :

```
import { Jumbotron }  from 'reactstrap'
```

Comment: But it is written everywhere that if ``export default Jumbotron`` is written, then you can safely write ``import Jumbotron from 'reactstrap';``. That would import Jumbotron only. When I use curly braces, I noticein the build out put that all components of reactstrap are being imported, also those that I don't need at all.

Comment: My goodness, Now I realise what is happeneing exactly. The modules are being imported through index.js, not their individual JS files.

Comment: @SatishTyagi, but in that case you need to point to that exact file , `from 'reactstrap';` this will point to `index.js` and if you check `index.js` you won't find `export default Jumbotron`

Comment: Thanks for the most amazing answer, I've seen to my question.

Comment: @SatishTyagi, Glad to know, it helped. :)

Comment: But as I said on applying curly braces, every module from reactstrap was being imported as seen in bundle output.

Comment: For that you can use `webpack`, it has many plugins to just improve the bundle size, remove unnecessary imports and so on...

Comment: On using 'reactstrap/Jumbotron', it is saying module not found!

Comment: Yes I think so, you can use the second one, same thing works with angular with web pack, I think for that needed some configuration on web pack side.

Comment: The exact location of all the reactstrap components is '/reactstrap/es/Component'. After doing this, it worked.  But I think that is very inefficient thing to do. So what to do to remove unnecesary imports?

Comment: @SatishTyagi, i think you need to look into webpack plugins for that

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your build setup and/or how the library code is setup. Some libraries are built in a way that won't import the entire library when you use curly braces. You can also have something enabled in your build tools called "tree shaking" which will remove all code that is unused.

I'm guessing what you were trying to do was import Jumbotron individually which is a safe bet when you are unsure if the whole lib will be imported. Again, it depends on the file structure of the library but you are probably missing the sub-directory in your import. There should be directories inside of the node_module folder for each component. Might be something like `node_modules/reactstrap/Jumbotron`. The default export you saw was probably on the `Jumbotron` file. When you use `import Jumbotron from 'reactstrap'` you are asking it do find a default export for the "main" file of the library. This would be defined in the `package.json` file of the library.

What you need to do is add the sub-directory to your import like so (just guessing here) `import Jumbotron from 'reactstrap/Jumbotron'`. Just think of `reactstrap/` being the root directory of the library, you can select any file like you normally would.

If you are using webpack, there's this awesome plugin where you can check to see what is included in your bundles just to make sure you are indeed only importing the code that you need https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer